# Primefaces calendar component from Timestamp JPA model field

Tags: java, jpa, primefaces

How to use primefaces calendar with jpa model where date and time is java.sql.Timestamp ?

Comment: why do you simply convert it to java.util.date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would have to implement your own converter, register it in faces-config, and use it in the calendar.

```
<p:calendar >
    <f:converter converterId="YourRegisteredConverter" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: That was too easy to think about it:/